# How to get schema's where used list?

Tags: schema, where-used

I want to get the schema's where used list of page templates, schemas etc.,provided with schema ID?
Please help on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CoreService:

```
 var list = ClientAdmin.GetList("tcm:1-1-8", new UsingItemsFilterData());
 var listXml = ClientAdmin.GetListXml("tcm:1-1-8", new UsingItemsFilterData());
```

Tom.NET:

```
schema.GetListUsingItems();
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how to get that 'Where used' list's publication names?

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: It is throwing an error for me like "LocationInfo" cannot be resolved or is not a field. Its the same with "item"

Comment: That is probably because your list is empty. Can you first check this?

Comment: No my list is not empty. I am able to read all the where used values.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. It will not work. We do not output publication title in list items. So you need to read each item from the list individually and get its LocationInfo.ContextRepository.Title or you can use GitListXml (added to my answer) and parse xml for Publication property.

Answer (score 3):

For this scenario, you can try the following using core service as there is no built in methods for this:

```
    UsingItemsFilterData filterCriteria = new UsingItemsFilterData();
    filterCriteria.BaseColumns = ListBaseColumns.Id;
    filterCriteria.IncludeLocalCopies = true;
    var resultList =CoreServiceClient.GetList("SchemaURI", filterCriteria);
```

If you don't want to use or have core service the same can be achieved using TOM.Net API, there is a method on `IdentifiableObject` called `HasUsingItems()` which will give you the details also. Check this [link](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/11199/i-want-to-get-where-used-status-of-component-component-template-page-template) once !!

You can have a look in this [link](https://tridionwithanupam.wordpress.com/2016/02/29/tridion-coreserviceclient-provider-github/)
which will give you ideas on how to use core service more effectively for similar kind of scenarios.

Let me know if this helps !!